# Bootstrap multiselect only works on first use

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using Bootstrap v3.0.0

The multiselect control's generated markup is comprised of a `<select>` and a `<div>` containing a `<button>` and a `<ul>`.

The `<ul>` seems to be what's actually displayed to the user. The problem I'm having is that everything works fine for the first time the user interacts with the control, but once the control has been opened, regardless of whether any selections have been made, after the control closes it can never be reopened unless you refresh the page.

I looked at the markup the control is generating and I noticed that before the control has been interacted with the `<ul>` looks like the following:

```
    <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 800px; overflow: hidden auto;">
        <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all"><a tabindex="0" class="multiselect-all"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="multiselect-all">  Select all</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="Active"><input type="checkbox" value="A"> Active</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="Disability"><input type="checkbox" value="D"> Disability</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="Pending"><input type="checkbox" value="P"> Pending</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="Terminated"><input type="checkbox" value="T"> Terminated</label></a></li>
    </ul>
```

But once the control has been interacted with, regardless if a selection was made, the markup changes to:

```
    <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 800px; overflow: hidden auto; display: none;">
        <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all active"><a tabindex="0" class="multiselect-all"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="multiselect-all">  Select all</label></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="Active"><input type="checkbox" value="A"> Active</label></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="Disability"><input type="checkbox" value="D"> Disability</label></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="Pending"><input type="checkbox" value="P"> Pending</label></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="Terminated"><input type="checkbox" value="T"> Terminated</label></a></li>
    </ul>
```

`display: none;` is being added to the `<ul>` style attribute. I'm not sure where it's coming from. None of my javascript touches the generated markup. If I use the dev console in chrome to remove the `display: none;` attribute the control works again for one interaction before it adds `display: none;` back to the `<ul>` causing the control to no longer open again.

The multiselect still behaves as if everything was working, with the `onDropdownShown` and `onDropdownHidden` events still firing.